Does this code adding -256 to a uint8 fail in numpy 2 due to NEP 50?
The following code works in numpy 1.26.4, but not in numpy  2.0.0rc1, giving

OverflowError: Python integer -256 out of bounds for int8

import numpy as np
np.array([1], dtype=np.int8) + (-256)

Is that expected? Is it due to NEP 50 adoption? If so, which part of NEP 50 mandates this new behavior?

See the NEP 50 discussion.

Yeah, that's NEP 50 behavior. Quoting NEP 50:

This proposal uses a “weak scalar” logic. This means that Python int, float, and complex are not assigned one of the typical dtypes, such as float64 or int64. Rather, they are assigned a special abstract DType, similar to the “scalar” hierarchy names: Integral, Floating, ComplexFloating.
When promotion occurs (as it does for ufuncs if no exact loop matches), the other DType is able to decide how to regard the Python scalar. E.g. a UInt16 promoting with an Integral will give UInt16.


At no time is the value used to decide the result of this promotion. The value is only considered when it is converted to the new dtype; this may raise an error.

Before, the value of the Python int -256 would have been examined to determine what result dtype to use. Now, adding a Python int to data of int8 dtype always converts the Python int to int8 dtype. If the value doesn't fit in int8 dtype, you get this error.
